Changing users.id To A UUID After Livewire Install Breaks All Breeze Tests
In my Laravel 11 project, altering the primary ID of the Users table to a UUID causes all tests to fail. This is a new project where I've only installed Breeze with AlpineJS, with Livewire being the only other package installed. I'm utilizing Windows 11 and Sail as a Dev Container, with MySQL serving as my database for this project. I've encountered this issue three times to date.
What I Have Done
I changed the default incremental integer type of the id column of the users table with a UUID type, following the instructions on the Laravel website (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys).
Users model
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasUuids;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];
    }
}


Migration file for users table
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('password_reset_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->primary();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });

        Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->primary();
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
            $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
            $table->longText('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_reset_tokens');
        Schema::dropIfExists('sessions');
    }
};


At this point, I do a php artisan optimize, run the tests, and everything is green.
The Breaking Change
At this point, I install Livewire, do another php artisan optimize, and run the tests, and everything is still green. But then, in my normal development process, the tests run red. In my development process, I do not change anything in the files above—no relationships or anything.
What I Expect to Happen
I was expecting the tests to all be green, but instead, I got the following:

Please help! I am going coocoo.

I found out that doing artisan optimize breaks a few things when Laravel is in a testing environment. To fix this, you've gotta do a composer dump-autoload --optimize to repair things.
